# How to group the input fields in array of objects in js (See image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have to do validation for scheduling multiple and dynamic departments for audits as shown in the image.

The issue is I have to group these input values Dates,From and To in a js array of objects using date.
eg:
All the time slots should come together under same date. Something like below.

```
schedule_obj=[
        {"18-11-2017":[
            {"From":"08:00am","To":"10:am"},
            {"From":"10.00am","To":"12:00pm"}
        ]},
        {"19-11-2017":[
            {"From":"08:00am","To":"10:am"},
            {"From":"10.00am","To":"12:00pm"}
        ]}
    ];
```

Date field has class `date`

From field has class `from`

To field has class `to`

[image: Example of the issue]

How to retrieve each field from that array?

Comment: If I understood correctly, then you have UI ready and you want to create an object from this UI that look like above example? Also, how are you going to handle departments?

Comment: I want to create array just to validate dates and times that is other part. First I needed how to group them and retrieve the values.

Comment: Can you create a fiddler/plunker with simplified problem. It would be easy to make a solution in that case.

Comment: I need to see the HTML source of the UI to work on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use object instead of array, like this

```
let scheduled_audits = {
    "18-11-2017":[
        {"From":"08:00am","To":"10:am"},
        {"From":"10.00am","To":"12:00pm"}
    ],
    "19-11-2017":[
        {"From":"08:00am","To":"10:am"},
        {"From":"10.00am","To":"12:00pm"}
    ]
};
// ...
displaySchedule(scheduled_audits["18-11-2017"]);
```